# Calculating the number of weeks for each year based on dates using R

Tags: r, date, week-number

I have a dataset with dates of 2 different years (2009 and 2010) and would like to have the corresponding week number for each date.

My dataset is similar to this:

```
  anim <- c(012,023,045,098,067)
  dob <- c("01-09-2009","12-09-2009","22-09-2009","10-10-2010","28-10-2010")
  mydf <- data.frame(anim,dob)
  mydf
    anim    dob
1   12   01-09-2009
2   23   12-09-2009
3   45   22-09-2009
4   98   10-10-2010
5   67   28-10-2010
```

I would like to have variable "week" in the third column with the corresponding week numbers for each date.

EDIT:
Note: Week one begins on January 1st, week two begins on January 8th for each year

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Baz

Comment: @nOp: not at all. I am working on a set of data (10,000 animals) and needed to calculate the corresponding week numbers for the set of dates that I have.

Comment: This is very weird definition of week of year -- are you sure about it? For instance it makes weeks start on different weekday every year...

Comment: @mbq -- But animals don't care about weekdays! This definition ensures that, e.g., week 1 always refers to the exact same part of the year (with whatever that entails about typical weather etc.)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: not true.  I'm an animal, and I care.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: Touche. Why did I ever think such a glaring corner case would go unnoticed -- on a programming site, no less?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of "week of year"

> EDIT: Note: Week one begins on January 1st, week two begins on January 8th for each year

differs from the standard ones supported by `strftime`:

```
%U
    Week of the year as decimal number (00–53) using Sunday as the first day 1 
    of the week (and typically with the first Sunday of the year as day 1 of 
    week 1). The US convention.
%W
    Week of the year as decimal number (00–53) using Monday as the first day 
    of week (and typically with the first Monday of the year as day 1 of week 
    1). The UK convention.
```

So you need to compute it based on the day-of-year number.

```
mydf$week <- (as.numeric(strftime(as.POSIXct(mydf$dob, 
                                             format="%d-%m-%Y"), 
                                  format="%j")) %/% 7) + 1
```

Comment: Sorry for the definition which I provided. That was something that I put in myself in order to get me going. I sent an email to the company that I obtained the data from to confirm their numbering system and haven't received anything. I have decided to go with the numbering system which is supported by strftime. I apologise again for the confusing definition I provided!

Comment: That's fine.  Different definitions can be appropriate for different purposes.  As Josh said, "animals don't care about weekdays!" so it didn't seem unreasonable.

Answer (score 0):

**Post 2011 Answer**

```
library(lubridate)
mydf$week <- week(mydf$week)
```

`lubridate` package is straight-forward for day-to-day tasks like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do how many weeks (or 7 day periods) have passed between your date of interest and the first day of the year, regardless of what day of the week it was on the first of the year, the following is a solution (using `floor_date` from lubridate).

```
mydf$weeks <- difftime(mydf$dob, floor_date(mydf$dob, "year"), units = c("weeks")))
```